# Layout design changes if device language is Arabic

Tags: android, android-layout, constants, android-constraintlayout, arabic

I'm encountering a layout issue in my Android app related to a custom dialog. In English mode, the dialog displays perfectly with a width set to match_parent. However, when switching to Arabic mode, the width seems to shrink, and the layout appears as if it's wrapping content.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

    </data>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/margin_padding20"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/margin_padding0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_padding20"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_padding20"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_padding32"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_padding32"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnCrossIcon"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:src="@drawable/iconoir_cancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMsgSuccess"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnCrossIcon"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_padding20"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                style="@style/TextStyleMediumRegular"
                android:text="@string/success"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMsgSuccess1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvMsgSuccess"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                style="@style/TextStyleMediumRegular"
                android:text="@string/your_application_has_been_submitted"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/btnBackToSearch"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvMsgSuccess1"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_padding48"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                android:text="@string/back_to_job_search"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/blue"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_bg_blue"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

That is how i am inflating dialog layout:

```
class ApplyJobDialog(context: Context) : Dialog(context), View.OnClickListener {
        private lateinit var binding: ApplyjobMassageDialogBinding
    
    
        init {
            setCancelable(true)
        }
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            binding = ApplyjobMassageDialogBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
            setContentView(binding.root)
            binding.btnBackToSearch.setOnClickListener(this)
            binding.btnCrossIcon.setOnClickListener(this)
        }
    
        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            if (v != null) {
                when (v.id) {
    
                    R.id.btnBackToSearch ->{
                        //listener?.onBackToJobSearchClicked()
                        dismiss()
                        val intent = Intent(context, Homepage::class.java)
                        context.startActivity(intent)
    
                    }
    
                    R.id.btnCrossIcon ->{
                       dismiss()
                    }
    
                }
            }
        }
    
    }
```

And by this i show the dialog:

```
ApplyJobDialog(context).show()
```

[image: issue_Screenshot]

How can I ensure that the dialog layout width remains consistent across different languages, especially when dealing with right-to-left text in Arabic mode?

Comment: Post how you're displaying the custom dialog and inflating this layout file.

Comment: @GabeSechan I have added more info in the post. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make the button height and width fixed. it should work

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btnBackToSearch"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvMsgSuccess1"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_padding48"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:text="@string/back_to_job_search"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/blue"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_bg_blue"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp" />
```